# Tabs shifts to the top when I navigate to the previous screen .Keyboard issue in Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am building app using `Xamarin .forms` and facing keyboard issue in the android app.

My app has two pages one with tabs and another page has an editor and with bottom a post button UI. When I click on editor than the bottom layout goes above the keyboard and when I press back button and navigate to previous page which has bottom tabs and `listview`, the tabs goes to the middle of the screen with white space below and when I scroll the list view that white space remains there.

I have tried with `adjust pan`, `resize`, `adjust nothing`.

Comment: are you using `windowSoftInputMode` in android project menifest.xml file

Comment: yes I am using it .    Window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.AdjustNothing);

        }

        public override void OnBackPressed()
        {
            base.OnBackPressed();
            HideTheKeyboard();
        }
        public void HideTheKeyboard()
        {
            Window.SetSoftInputMode(Android.Views.SoftInput.AdjustPan);
        }

Comment: Try removing it. When you are asking question you supposed to show your code. Otherwise it's difficult to guess the issue. So edit you question & post code.